# Shouldn't GetLastWin32Error be reset if P/Invoke attribute SetLastError = true?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, pinvoke, unmanaged

I noticed that `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` was returning error 122 during the dispose method after a p/invoke to `Kernal32.CloseHandle(IntPtr p_handle)` even with the import attribute `SetLastError` set to true on the import definition.  I tracked the cause down to the creation of `new WindowsIdentity` just before the handle being closed and I'm wondering what the proper way to handle this is.

1. Should I only check for a Win32 error if CloseHandle returns false?
2. Forcefully SetLastError to 0 before p/invoking CloseHandle?
3. Forcefully SetLastError to 0 after `new WindowsIdentity(DangereousHandle)`

Point 3 seems immediately unreasonable to me, so I presume that's an obvious no.

Point 2 seems most reasonable, but perhaps unnecessarily aggressive. The only reason I would go with this instead of point 1 is because I'm not sure I have a guarantee that if CloseHandle returns false the error code will be relevant. Is that guaranteed by the function documentation?

Point 1 seems like it's what I should be doing. That is I should only be calling GetLastWin32Error when CloseHandle explicitly returns false and assume that the returned code will indicate why CloseHandle failed and not some prior unrelated Win API call.

**Code**

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace Common.InterOp
{
    // CloseHandle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

    internal static partial class Kernel32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    }
}
```

Here's where Close Handle is called

```cs
using Common.InterOp;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Common.InterOp
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

    public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true)
        { }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            int Win32Error =
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // <-- Already has code 122

            var Closed =
                Kernel32.CloseHandle(handle); // <-- has SetLastError=true attribute

            Win32Error =
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // <-- Still has code 122

            if (!Closed && Win32Error != 0) // This works, but is it correct?
                throw
                    new Win32Exception(Win32Error);

            return Closed;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code block that actually generates error 122 on the line that has `var WinID = new WindowsIdentity(DangerousHandle);`

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Common.InterOp;
using Common.Environment;

namespace Common.Authentication
{
    public static partial class Authentication
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticates the log on credentials of a Windows user.
        /// Returns a WindowsIdentity if authentication succeeds for the specified user; Otherwise returns null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p_userName">The user's Windows account name.</param>
        /// <param name="p_password">The user's Windows account password.</param>
        /// <param name="p_domainName">The user's domain name or the name of the local machine for non-networked accounts.</param>
        /// <returns>a <seealso cref="WindowsIdentity"/> if authentication succeeds for the specified user; Otherwise returns null.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Security.SecurityException"></exception>
        public static WindowsIdentity LogonUser(SecureString p_userName, SecureString p_password, SecureString p_domainName, LogonUserOptions p_logonOptions)
        {
            // The following functions seem related, but it's unclear if or in what scenario they would ever be required
            // DuplicateToken   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
            // DuplicateTokenEx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

            SafeTokenHandle UserAccountToken = null;

            try
            {
                using (var DecryptedUserName = new DecryptAndMarshallSecureString(p_userName))
                using (var DecryptedPassword = new DecryptAndMarshallSecureString(p_password))
                using (var DecryptedDomainName = new DecryptAndMarshallSecureString(p_domainName))
                {
                    // Call LogonUser, passing the unmanaged (and decrypted) copies of the SecureString credentials.
                    bool ReturnValue =
                        AdvApi32.LogonUser(
                            p_userName: DecryptedUserName.GetHandle(),
                            p_domainName: DecryptedDomainName.GetHandle(),
                            p_password: DecryptedPassword.GetHandle(),
                            p_logonType: p_logonOptions.Type,           // LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                            p_logonProvider: p_logonOptions.Provider,   // LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                            p_userToken: out UserAccountToken);

                    // Get the Last win32 Error and throw an exception.
                    int Win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (!ReturnValue && UserAccountToken.DangerousGetHandle() == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw
                            new Win32Exception(Win32Error);

                    // The token that is passed to the following constructor must  
                    // be a primary token in order to use it for impersonation.

                    var DangerousHandle = UserAccountToken.DangerousGetHandle();

                    Win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // No error

                    var WinID = new WindowsIdentity(DangerousHandle);

                    Win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // error 122

                    // Kernel32.SetLastError(0); // Resets error to 0
                    Sleep.For(0);
                    //new Win32Exception(Win32Error); // Also resets error to 0

                    Win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // Still error 122 unless one of the reset lines above is uncommented

                    return WinID;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (UserAccountToken != null)
                    UserAccountToken.Dispose(); // This calls CloseHandle which is where I first noticed the error being non-zero
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2014, 08, 09**

Updated class based on hvd's comments and answer.

```cs
using Common.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;

namespace Common.InterOp
{
    // SafeHandle.ReleaseHandle Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.releasehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206969/shouldnt-getlastwin32error-be-reset-if-p-invoke-attribute-setlasterror-true

    [jwdebug(2014, 08, 09, "releaseHandleFailed MDA http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85eak4a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx")]
    public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true)
        { }

        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
        override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            // Here, we must obey all rules for constrained execution regions. 

            return
                Kernel32.CloseHandle(handle);

            // If ReleaseHandle failed, it can be reported via the 
            // "releaseHandleFailed" managed debugging assistant (MDA).  This
            // MDA is disabled by default, but can be enabled in a debugger 
            // or during testing to diagnose handle corruption problems. 
            // We do not throw an exception because most code could not recover 
            // from the problem.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although not related to your actual question, it doesn't look like you should be throwing any exception at all. The example on [`SafeHandle.ReleaseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.releasehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) even uses `CloseHandle`, exactly like your class: if that fails, it simply returns `false`.

Comment: @hvd fantastic... now I need to read up on MDAs at some point... maybe some night when I have insomnia. Thanks for the extra info! I'll add an edit to my question, with the code as it stands right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Point 1 seems like it's what I should be doing.

Yes, that's exactly right. Forget the .NET P/Invoke aspect of your question, and look at the [original function description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call **GetLastError**.

The description doesn't say that calling `GetLastError` is meaningful when the function succeeds, and as you found out, it indeed isn't meaningful, so you shouldn't be calling it in that case.